# itertools: creating a 2d iterator

Tags: python, python-itertools

I am trying to use itertools to make this code perform better and be more pythonic

```
def get_permutations():
out = []
for a in range(0,6):
    for b in range(0, 6):
        for c in range(0, 6):
            for d in range(0, 6):
                for e in range(0, 6):
                    for f in range(0, 6):
                        out.append([a,b,c,d,e,f])
return out
```

I think I should be using itertools.permutations and itertools.chain, but I'm not sure how to put them together to get the equivalent result either as a list or an iterator. If you have another solution that does not use itertools, I will also consider it.

Comment: Isn't that just `itertools.product(range(6), repeat=6)`? See https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product

Comment: These aren't permutations, but the cartesian product, as jonsharpe mentions. using `itertools.product` might make it faster, but it won't change the algorithmic complexity (which is pretty horrendous here).

Comment: @StefanPochmann assuming `range(6)` is variable. If not, then using `itertools.product` or just these nested loops won't make an appreciable difference at all.

Comment: jonrsharpe, you are right. Post that as an answer so I can accept it.
juanpa, yes, I acknowledge the performance is pretty horrendous.

Answer (score 1):

Are you not looking for `itertools.combinations_with_replacement([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 6)` ? :)